# ArithmeticException: Function does not accept floating point Not-a-Number values. PointwiseSign() not working in Unity WebGL

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a function in Unity that currently works in the Unity editor and the Windows build, but not in the WebGL build. In the browser I'm getting the following error:

```
  at System.Math.Sign (System.Double value) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Vector+<>c.<DoPointwiseSign>b__31_0 (System.Double x) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Func`2[T,TResult].Invoke (T arg) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Storage.DenseVectorStorage`1+<>c__DisplayClass30_0`1[T,TU].<MapToUnchecked>b__0 (System.Int32 a, System.Int32 b) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Action`2[T1,T2].Invoke (T1 arg1, T2 arg2) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at MathNet.Numerics.Threading.CommonParallel.For (System.Int32 fromInclusive, System.Int32 toExclusive, System.Int32 rangeSize, System.Action`2[T1,T2] body) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Storage.DenseVectorStorage`1[T].MapToUnchecked[TU] (MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Storage.VectorStorage`1[T] target, System.Func`2[T,TResult] f, MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Zeros zeros, MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.ExistingData existingData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Storage.VectorStorage`1[T].MapTo[TU] (MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Storage.VectorStorage`1[T] target, System.Func`2[T,TResult] f, MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Zeros zeros, MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.ExistingData existingData) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector`1[T].Map (System.Func`2[T,TResult] f, MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector`1[T] result, MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Zeros zeros) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Vector.DoPointwiseSign (MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector`1[T] result) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Action`1[T].Invoke (T obj) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector`1[T].PointwiseUnary (System.Action`1[T] f) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector`1[T].PointwiseSign () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at EBM.Integrate (MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector`1[T] T, System.Int32 years, System.Int32 timesteps) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at EBM.Calc (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] input, System.Int32 years, System.Int32 timesteps) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at World.Calc (System.Boolean useTemp, System.Int32 years, System.Int32 steps) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at World.Init () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at GameManager.Awake () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
 
(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

The function that is causing the error is the Integrate() function which is here:

```
/// <summary> Does entire timestep integration calculation </summary>
    public static (Matrix<double>, Matrix<double>) Integrate(Vector<double> T = null, int years = 0, int timesteps = 0)
    {
        T = T ?? 7.5f + 20 * (1 - 2 * x.PointwisePower(2));
        years = years == 0 ? dur : years;
        timesteps = timesteps == 0 ? nt : timesteps;
        Matrix<double> Tfin = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(bands, nt, 0);
        Matrix<double> Efin = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(bands, nt, 0);
        Matrix<double> T0fin = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(bands, nt, 0);
        Matrix<double> ASRfin = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(bands, nt, 0);
        
        //Matrix<double> tfin = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense()np.linspace(0, 1, nt);
        Vector<double> Tg = Vector<double>.Build.DenseOfVector(T);
        Vector<double> E = Tg * cw;
        
        for (var (i, p) = (0, 0); i < years; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < timesteps; j++)
            {
                /*              if (j % (nt / 100f) == 0)
                                {
                                    Efin.SetColumn(p, E);
                                    Tfin.SetColumn(p, T);
                                    p++;
                                }*/
                Vector<double> alpha = E.PointwiseSign().PointwiseMultiply(aw).Map(x => x < 0 ? aI : x); // aw * (E > 0) + ai * (E < 0)
                Vector<double> C = alpha.PointwiseMultiply(S.Row(j)) + cg_tau * Tg - A + F; // alpha * S[i, :] + cg_tau * Tg - A
                Vector<double> T0 = C / (M - k * Lf / E);

                if (i == dur - 1)
                {
                    Efin.SetColumn(j, E);// [":", i] = E;
                    Tfin.SetColumn(j, T);//[":", i] = T;
                    T0fin.SetColumn(j, T0);//[":", i] = T0;
                    ASRfin.SetColumn(j, alpha.PointwiseMultiply(S.Row(j)));//[":", i] = alpha * S[i, ":"];
                }

                T = Sign0(GreatOrE, E) / cw + Sign0(Less, Sign0(Less, E, T0)); // E/cw*(E >= 0)+T0*(E < 0)*(T0 < 0)
                E = E + dt * (C - M * T + Fb);
                var mklfe = M - k * Lf / E;
                var signlesset0 = Sign0(Less, E, T0);

                /*# Implicit Euler on Tg
                # latent heat transport
                # n.b. this is semi-implicit, with some derivatives are
                # calculated on the previous time step*/
                var q = RH * saturation_specific_humidity(Tg, Ps);
                var rhs1 = (dt * diffop / cg) * (Lv * q / cp);
                Tg = (kappa - Matrix<double>.Build.DiagonalOfDiagonalVector(
                    Sign0(Less, signlesset0, dc / mklfe) // np.diag(dc / (M - kLf / E) * (T0 < 0) * (E < 0)
                )).Solve(Tg + rhs1 + dt_tau * (
                    Sign0(GreatOrE, E) / cw + (aI * S.Row(j) - A + F). // E / cw * (E >= 0) + (ai * S[i, :] - A)
                    Map2((a, b) => b != 0 ? a / b : 0, // funky division
                        Sign0(Less, signlesset0, mklfe)) // (M - kLf / E) * (T0 < 0) * (E < 0)
                ));
            }
        }
```

Based on the stack trace, it looks like the issue is with the line `Vector<double> alpha = E.PointwiseSign().PointwiseMultiply(aw).Map(x => x < 0 ? aI : x);`

What I'm not understanding is why the code works in other versions of the game, but breaks in the WebGL version. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not a value is usually the result of an undefined mathematical operation .. such as e.g. division by `0` .. as soon as any value used in an expression is "Not a value" the entire expression also returns "Not a value" .. so I would suggest you [Debug your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and check where exactly you have a not defined value/expression happening

Answer (score 0):

Figured out kind of a solution to this -- for some reason, this was breaking randomly in Unity 2019.3, but upgraded to 2019.4 and now the function seems to be working consistently. Might have something to do with how the different versions convert the function into WebGL.